# Hadith that asks to be wary of Huffaz

Tags: hadith, reference-request

I once read a Hadith in which Prophet Muhammad() warns us to be wary of Huffaz as  many of the mischief makers are Huffaz.

Can anyone find the reference of any such Hadith?

Comment: It sounds very strange. Perhaps you read something about the Khawarij?

Comment: @Harun I know that Khawarij have similar reports about them. But this is not one of them.

Comment: How about people who recite the qur'an but don't follow it or scholars who make lawful and unlawful according their nafs I'm not sure that the hadith you look for actually say they are hufadh..

Comment: @Medi1Saif Actually, I found the Hadith. It has several versions. Most versions are translated as 'reciters' and one is translated as 'memorizers' which is quoted in this [fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/answers/20803/reward-for-memorizing-quraan?&ampcf=1) by IslamQA. But, it doesn't say to beware of them explicitly. Maybe you could look into it.